# Is Microsoft.Practices.Composite earlier version of Microsoft.Practices.Prism?

Tags: c#, prism

In my project I use some kind of SDK libraries written by external team. These libraries are using Prism. For some reasons we had to rollback to previous version of their SDK and now build is failed trying to find reference to Microsoft.Practices.Composite.dll. Am I right that this is how Prism library was called in earlier version or is it something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Pre v4, Prism's dlls included `Microsoft.Practices.Composite.dll` but, as of v4, this has been rolled into `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll` along with some other functionality.

The documented list of changes is this:

> - The Composite Application Library was renamed to the Prism Library.
> - The Composite and Composite.Presentation portions of the namespaces were removed and the Composite and Composite.Presentation assemblies collapsed into a single assembly named Microsoft.Practices.Prism.
> - The Microsoft.Practices.Prism libraries for Silverlight and WPF now register the Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions, Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands, and Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel namespaces with the http://www.codeplex.com/prism xmlns definition.
> - Several reusable user interface (UI)–based behaviors were extracted into the Prism.Interactivity assembly, including the interaction request behavior.
> - You can now use MEF as the dependency injection container. This functionality required two new projects in the Prism Library solutions: Prism.MefExtensions.Desktop and Prism.MefExtensions.Silverlight. These projects create a new assembly, Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.dll, in the respective Desktop and Silverlight folders. Also included in the solutions are new unit test projects for the new functionality.

[Source here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430871%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.Practices.Composite` is from `Prism 2.x`

The currently version of `Prism is 4.1`!

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.composite.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems with the upgrade/rollback, you might take a look into:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921073%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx

and, more specifically about the SDK's assemblies:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921144(v=pandp.40).aspx#AssemblyRef

While these documents talk about the upgrade process, it should help you understanding what should be taken care of during a rollback.